# Is there a way to get recently deleted pages/databased in Notion through their API

Tags: notion-api, notion

Is there a way to get recently deleted pages/databased in Notion through their API?
I noticed that there is an archived property on pages and databased and I know that there is a search endpoint that can be sorted by last_edit_time (https://api.notion.com/v1/search) but, I don't see any way to filter by the archived field.

I was hoping https://api.notion.com/v1/search would allow for some sort of filtering or I was hoping that archiving a page/database would cause last_edit_time to be mutated, but I don't see any documentation showing that to be the case.

Comment: From what I find in the internet it does not seem possible atm. 
For me the major problem here is that the `last_updated_*` properties are not being changed on archive. 

So, without directly accessing the page via ID or luckily having it in the results of a query the outside world will not receive that information via API.

I am considering to add a Template button that sets a custom prop to `archived` and then adding a block that prompts the user to "delete the page now".